# Firestore rules on collection snapshot listener

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following security rule defined on a Firestore collection `/test`

```
    match /test/{test} {
        allow get: if resource.data.readable == true
    }
```

And half the elements in the collection have `readable` field set to `true` and half to `false`.

The `get` requests work correctly whereby I can retrieve only the elements set to `true`.

However, in the following snapshot listener I get nothing returned:

```
onSnapshot(collection(db, "test"), (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach( a => {
        console.log(a.data());
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The query for the listener is failing entirely because the query isn't matching the requirements of the rule.  The rule requires that the query only request documents where readable == true.  The rules [will **not** filter the results of the collection query for you](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) - the query must specify the correct filter.

If you change your query to ask for only readable documents, it should work.

```
const query = query(collection(db, "test"), where("readable", "==", true))
onSnapshot(query, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach( a => {
        console.log(a.data());
    })
});
```

Also note that this has nothing to do with the fact that you're using a listener.  The query would also fail if you used `getDocs()` on it directly.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. However, the rule does run, I know this because if I change the rule to resource.data.get('readable', null) == null, I get all the elements returned by the query.